# "Unresolved external symbol" errors when creating a Qt GUI application with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I am trying to make a very simple GUI application, on the top of some C++ code which I wrote. My problem could be simplifed to the following:

```
#include <QtGui\QDialog>
void setup(int argc, char **argv) {
    QDialog dlg;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setup(argc, argv);
}
```

I configured my Qt library, and I am pretty sure that the libraries are compatible with my Visual Studio 2010 (other projects worked fine), but I don't know if I should create a header file. I am always receiving these errors:

```
>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall QDialog::~QDialog(void)" (??1QDialog@@UAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QDialog::QDialog(class QWid.................
```

Comment: Are you linking with Qt? If not, you'll need to do so.

Comment: i added the "include" and the "lib" ( additional dependacies ... ) anything else ?

Comment: Maybe — I've never used Visual Studio to make a Qt application.

Comment: if "lib" is only the library path, you'll also have to configure which libs to link against, namely QtCore and QtGui. On the command line, it would look like this: -L/path/to/qt/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore etc.

Comment: And also you will need a QApplication (to run an event loop) if you want to create and show qwidgets

Answer (score 0):

The errors you got signals that VS compiler cannot determine addresses of invocation the external functions you've used, namely ctor and dtor for QDialog class object. To avoid such errors you should specify the location of the libraries containing the definitions of that functions. In order to achieve this you should use "Project Properties"->"Configuration Properties"->"Linker"->"Input", then in the "Additional Dependencies" line input the absolute path to the external libs (e.g. "C:\Qt\4.8.3\lib\QtGui.lib").
I suppose if you only got that errors you mentioned you set your include paths correctly. So specifying input libraries should help.
For the future I'd suggest you install [Qt VS Add-in](http://qt-project.org/downloads). It adds some options to an ordinary VS "Create new project" dialog, so you can choose "New Qt project" and all the required paths will be set automatically.